# MS SQL Stored procedure to generate a script create a copy of existing database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-scripts

I want some help with creating a copy of my database in SQL Server 2008. So I found this article 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/
which tells how to generate a script that creates a copy of the entire database including the data, key constraints, triggers etc, this is great but I want to automate the process such that once every month or so I can run the stored procedure that will generate this script to create a copy of the database with all the current data and run the script to create a copy of database. Is this possible to do? Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it would be acceptable to perform a backup and restore of the database - this is what the code might look like to `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` AdventureWorks

```
BACKUP DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] TO  DISK = N'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2012.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'AdventureWorks2012-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Note that the "copied" database's name is AdventureWorks2012_Copy

```
RESTORE DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012_Copy] FROM  DISK = N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2012.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Copy_Data.mdf',  
MOVE N'AdventureWorks2012_Log' TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Copy_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

The code is a little verbose as a result of it being generated by scripting SSMS GUI functionality.

You may also want to consider whether or not you want to delete the `.bak` files, or what process you might want to put in place to do this repeatedly.